# How to create simple child thread in assembly x86_64(Linux, gas syntax)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

How to move "compute" function in second thread? Pls give me simple example with some details how it works. I have tried to search some code examples on the web, but no result.

```
.data
.balign 16
vectorA: .double 4.0, 4.0
vectorB: .double 2.0, 2.0

.text
.globl main, compute
main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  callq compute
  xorq %rax, %rax
  popq %rbp  
  retq

compute:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  movapd vectorA(%rip), %xmm0
  movapd vectorB(%rip), %xmm1
  movq $1000000000, %rcx
  lp:
    mulpd %xmm1, %xmm0
    divpd %xmm1, %xmm0
  loop lp
  popq %rbp
  retq
```

Comment: You need to use `clone`, see [this nice page](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2015/05/15/).

Comment: Thanks, hope i'll can understand nasm syntax.

Comment: Related: [Assembly clone syscall thread function not called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60657004) on how to actually use it to get another thread started with a stack and a function pointer.